# how to save custom css for external websites

Tags: css, customization

I want to save my own custom css for specific sites i.e. "Netflix", "Google", etc. This is something I have been trying/failing to do for a while. My best idea has been to try find a way to customize the local user agent stylesheet to override the sites css file. Maybe use the "!important" tag? My results have not proved to be very effective. If you know anywhere that would be better to post this please let me know!

Comment: `!important` does *not* saves your console-edited stylesheets. ON page refresh you'll get the good old Google design ;) You might want to Google for tools/extensions that help you save such changes.

Comment: assuming you want to target just one browser you could write an extension for such browser

Comment: @chepe263 he'll not gonna do that

Comment: Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey will do that for you. http://somethingididnotknow.wordpress.com/2013/07/01/change-page-styles-with-greasemonkeytampermonkey/

Comment: Depending on the browser, there are ways to set up a custom style sheet. You can edit the Firefox custom style sheet directly. For Chrome, there is at least one add-on. In either case, using `!important` is often the easiest way to override the site's styles. It's fine to do it in a use case like this. Let us know what browser/platform you are on for further advice, or do some googling.

Comment: I will take a look at greasemonkey and tampermonkey also I am well aware !important does not save console edited text nor is it good web programming I only mentioned it as a easy way to override all css except inline. and last but not least I use Chrome in combination with firebug lite  I am running mac os x 10.9